# Java Online Judge Solution error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to solve problem #299 - Train Swapping in website UVa Online judge. The code I have works fine for independent test cases. However, when I use the sample input they provide, my program omits one of the test cases, the last one to be more specific:

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tester {
  void problem(){
    Scanner imput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numT =imput.nextInt();
    int numL, aux, swaps=0;
    int [] train = new int [50];

    for (int i =0; i<numT; i++) {
      numL = imput.nextInt();

      for (int m =0; m< numL; m++) {
        train[m]=imput.nextInt();
      }

      for (int j=0; j<numL; j++) {
        if (train[j]>train[j+1]) {
          for (int k =j; k<numL-1;k++) {
            aux = train[k];
            train[k]=train[k+1];
            train[k+1]=aux;
            swaps++;
          }
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Optimal train swapping takes "+swaps+" swaps.");
      swaps = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Example Input:

```
3
3
1 3 2
4
4 3 2 1
2
2 1
```

Example Output:

```
Optimal train swapping takes 1 swaps.
Optimal train swapping takes 6 swaps.
Optimal train swapping takes 1 swaps.
```

My code prints until the second solution, then for some reason stops. I've tried to debug it and check what's going on step by step but it has driven me to a migraine point. Any insight is highly appreciated.

...
To be more precise it stops at the second **for** loop the third time around without taking anything into the array...and I don't know why!

Another thing I found out is that to solve this problem the number of swaps for the case of the middle is 6, therefore the bubble sort wont be useful here, since it makes over 10 swaps thus yielding a wrong output, this is a separate issue to the original one I presented however. I still haven't figure out why it stops the third time around the loop where I assign values to the array for the third time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange your loop like follows:

```
 for(int j=0; j<numL; j++){
 for(int k =j+1; k<numL;k++){
     if(train[j]>train[k]){
             aux = train[j];
             train[j]=train[k];
             train[k]=aux;
             swaps++;
        }
     }
 }
```

**Edited: for performance.**

You can minimize a for loop, if you organize your code like below:

```
public class Main { 
    static int sum=0;   
    public static void sort(String[] str){
        for(int i = 1; i < str.length; i++)
            if(Integer.parseInt(str[i])<Integer.parseInt(str[i-1])){
                String h = str[i];
                str[i] = str[i-1];
                str[i-1] = h;
                sum++;
                sort(str);
            }
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine().trim());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum = 0;
            int x = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine().trim());
            String s[] = in.readLine().trim().split(" +");
            sort(s);
            System.out.println("Optimal train swapping takes " + sum + " swaps.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, it works, however need the answer to be with my simple code, you think you can figure out why it stops where it stops?